# Phonegap HTML5's canvas' clearRect crashes the app

Tags: cordova, html5-canvas, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I'm using Phonegap 2.7.0, Android 4.2.2.

I'm trying to clear parts of a canvas, when I use the clearRect() function on my actual device, the screen turns blue.
But when I do it with the Android emulator, it works fine.

What is wrong here ?

Thanks

Comment: Some code would be helpful and you should definitely look into your device's log files.

Comment: Hey, Here is a code I've found online, showing a similar problem:

When using the Android emulator and clearRect() is called, it clears the canvas well.
But when I run the same code on my Galaxy S4, than clearRect() doesn't work and the canvas isn't cleared.

code:

Comment: var sigCanvas;
      var context;
      function initialize() {
  sigCanvas = document.getElementById("canvasSignature");
  context = sigCanvas.getContext("2d");
  context.strokeStyle = 'Black';
  context.lineWidth = 1;
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(0, 0);
  context.lineTo(sigCanvas.width, sigCanvas.height);
  context.stroke();
  context.closePath();
  if ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) {
   var drawer = {
   isDrawing: false,
   touchstart: function (coors) {
    context.clearRect(0,0, sigCanvas.width, sigCanvas.height);

Comment: Please add the code formatted and displayed as code to your original post, because this is unreadable. It does look like half the function is missing, though.

Answer (score 0):

I've also come across theis problem.
To solve this, rather than passing the realsize to `clearRect()`, you can pass one more pixel,like `clearRect(0,0,width+1,height+1)`.

Detail can be found here: http://browser.colla.me/show/canvas_crash_on_repeatedly_repaint